# How should I specify default values on Pydantic fields with "Validate Always" to satisfy type checkers?

Tags: python, pydantic

My type checker moans at me when I use snippets like this one [from the Pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always):

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class DemoModel(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime = None  # Expression of type "None" cannot be 
                         # assigned to declared type "datetime"

    @validator('ts', pre=True, always=True)
    def set_ts_now(cls, v):
        return v or datetime.now()
```

My workarounds so far have been:

```py
ts: datetime = datetime(1970, 1, 1)  # yuck
```

```py
ts: datetime = None  # type: ignore
```

```py
ts: Optional[datetime] = None  # Not really true. `ts` is not optional.
```

Is there a preferred way out of this conundrum?

Or is there a type checker I could use which doesn't mind this?

Comment: @daniel-quinn's solution is correct, but I'd argue that `ts` _is_ optional - the validator will set `ts=datetime.now()` if it hasn't been supplied at initialisation. So your third option (`Optional[datetime]`) also works.

Comment: @Ogaday that's an interesting take on what `Optional` means, but it'll mean I have to do `if DemoModel.ts:` everywhere, which is an unnecessary check because it'll always have a value.

Answer (score 22):

**New answer**

Use a [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization) with a `default_factory` for your dynamic default value:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class DemoModel(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime = Field(default_factory=datetime.now)
```

Your type hints are correct, the linter is happy and `DemoModel().ts is not None`.

From the `Field` docs:

> `default_factory`: a zero-argument callable that will be called when a default value is needed for this field. Among other purposes, this can be used to set dynamic default values.

Comment: This (the new answer) is pretty good, and has led me to some useful reading about `Field`. I think where the default value can be usefully put into a lambda, then this is the right approach. It's got some downsides though, because the factory is zero-argument: no `cls` to use class methods, or `values` to derive the default from.

Comment: I don't know if you can combine `Field`s with validators. You can potentially look at [custom Fields](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#custom-data-types) for more powerful behaviour, but it may be overkill.

Comment: Turns out you can combine `Field`s with validators and handle the dynamic default there instead of the `default_factory`

Answer (score 2):

If the field is required, then you just don't supply a default:

```
class DemoModel(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime
```

Pydantic will prevent you from instantiating an instance of `DemoModel` if you don't supply a `ts` argument in this case.

Comment: The whole point of `always=True` on the validator is "to set a dynamic default value." (qutote from [the docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always)). So I want to be able to instantiate without providing a value.

Comment: Yeah my bad.  I read the question and ignored the validator not realising that you were using the validator to set a default.  Ogaday's answer above looks like the right way to go for your case.